# Finding minimum for a function of four variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I would like to find the min of the following function,

```
-5 + 2 Sqrt[5] + 4 (5 - 3 Sqrt[5]) b^2 + Sqrt[2] (-1 + 2 b^2 - 2 a Sqrt[1 - a^2 - 
2 b^2] Cos[ρ - ϛ])
```

for `-1 ⩽ a ⩽ 1`
    `-((1 - a^2)/2)^(1/2) ⩽ b ⩽ ((1 - a^2)/2)^(1/2)`
    `0 ⩽ ρ ⩽ 2*Pi`
    `0 ⩽ ϛ ⩽ 2*Pi`

Comment: Seems like the sort of thing one finds in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

```
f = -5 + 2 Sqrt[5] + 4 (5 - 3 Sqrt[5]) b^2 + Sqrt[2] (-1 + 2 b^2 - 
 2 a Sqrt[1 - a^2 - 2 b^2] Cos[ρ - ϛ])

Minimize[{f, -1 ⩽ a ⩽ 1, -((1 - a^2)/2)^(1/2) ⩽ b ⩽ ((1 - a^2)/2)^(1/2), 
 0 ⩽ ρ ⩽ 2*Pi, 0 ⩽ ϛ ⩽ 2*Pi}, {a, b, ρ, ϛ}]
```

> `{5 - 4 Sqrt[5], {a -> 0, b -> -(1/Sqrt[2]), ρ -> 27/22, ϛ -> 1/22 (27 + 11 π)}}`